# Can't create docker image for .NET Core application

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my project file.

```
❯ ls                                                                                     ─╯
BosApp     BosApp.sln Dockerfile README.md
```

Inside the **BosApp** we have

```
ApiException.cs                               ShareModel.cs
BosApp.csproj                                 Startup.cs
Controllers                                   UserNotAuthorizedException.cs
Data                                          Views
Dockerfile                                    appsettings.Development.json
ExceptionMiddlewareExtensions.cs              appsettings.json
Migrations                                    bin
Models                                        libwkhtmltox.dll
Program.cs                                    libwkhtmltox.dylib
Properties                                    obj
RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware.cs           robots.json
RequestResponseLoggingMiddlewareExtensions.cs web.config
Services                                      wwwroot
```

**My docker file**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /APP

RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT docker

ENTRYPOINT dotnet run
```

In the terminal, inside the project structure where I have DockerFile, I am writing :

```
docker build -t bosapp-demo .
```

Output is this :

```
❯ docker build -t bosapp-demo .                                                          ─╯
Sending build context to Docker daemon  214.8MB
Step 1/9 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
 ---> 56a634b88a04
Step 2/9 : COPY . /app
 ---> dec32085afa9
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /APP
 ---> Running in 5575edfaab03
Removing intermediate container 5575edfaab03
 ---> 1bc0fb3179c0
Step 4/9 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 1138521bd5e0
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I am trying to create docker image first time and have that type of problem.

Any help and advice will be worth for me.

Comment: You are missing the .dll file. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

Comment: @RicardoPeres AFAIK, the question-asker's intent is to do the build inside the container. There wouldn't be a existing `.dll` file in this case to copy.

Comment: You’re right, sorry!

Comment: Why don't you use VS docker file creator? right click on your project then add Docker Support ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're specifying different directories:

```
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /APP
```

Try changing to:

```
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
```